# How does one use a literal {{ in a Mustache template?

Tags: escaping, mustache

How does one use a literal "{{" in a Mustache template?

On a side note, if I'm using custom tags, like `<%` and `%>`, is there a way to write "<%"?

Theoretically, I could use different tags, but I have too much code written using `{{` and `}}` to change it all.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just change the delimiters temporarily:

```
{{=<% %>=}}
{{Look at the curlies!}}
<%={{ }}=%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are outputting HTML you could use an HTML entity to avoid it (mustache doesn't have any way to escape the opening tag built in).

So to output `{{` you would write `&#123;{`.
To output `<%` you would write `&lt;%`.

Comment: @MindVirus Like I said Mustache doesn't have any way of escaping the opening tag built in. There are workarounds though. Like changing your delimiter, outputting the symbol, and then changing the delimiter back. There may be a better workaround depending out what you're outputting as well, like there is for HTML.

Comment: And `&#125;` for `}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{{` by itself quite easily. If you are trying to document something like `{{example}}` you could always pass in the first two cur lies with your data.

```
orphaned curlies are easy {{ <br>
{{curly}}example}} curlies are harder
```

Some simple rendering:

```
var data = { 'curly' : '{{'},
    tpl = $('#curly').html(),
    html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data);

document.write(html);​
```

Results in:

```
orphaned curlies are easy {{ 
{{example}} curlies are harder
```

Here's the [full working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/NMqQV/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without passing a variable?

Comment: You can't tell a parser to respect a pattern sometimes but not always hence the workarounds with variables and HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result with just add a couple of curly braces in the template,
as example: data: `const data = {"charsToBeEscaped": "<%"}` template: `a special char like that is perfectly rendered! {{{charsToBeEscaped}}}`, it generates:  `is perfectly rendered! <%`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a section lambda.

In mustache.js:

```
import Mustache from 'mustache';

const template = '{{ # literal }}{{Look at the curlies!}}{{ / literal }}';

const view = {
    literal: () => text => text
};

const output = Mustache.render(template, view);

console.log(output); // {{Look at the curlies!}}
```

Doing this of course means that nothing inside the `literal` section can be rendered which may or may not be desirable for your use case.