# how to print literal { in front of mustache variable

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have a mustache template where I would like to surround the variables with {}

```
var output = Mustache.render('<td>{{{start.lat}}, {{start.lon}}}</td>', routeObj);
```

I'd like this to output a `<td>` with the string: `{1.8978, 30.4545}`

{{{ has special meaning in mustache so it doesn't work. Is there a way to escape the first { in mustache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one use a literal {{ in a Mustache template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042926/how-does-one-use-a-literal-in-a-mustache-template)