# I am trying to render handlebars tags in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

Does anyone know how to render handlebars tags {{}} in a Meteor template?

I have no idea how to escape it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042926/how-does-one-use-a-literal-in-a-mustache-template?

Comment: thanks minitech.  My answer was not what was the answer in the link but I read down and found the solution.  I didn't even think to look under Mustache.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" spacebars way of escaping curly braces is by appending a vertical bar like this **{{|** 
This also works for triple braces: **{{{|**

Reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/2916

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

With a special thanks to minitech I need to use and HTML entity for the opening tag.  So `&#123;{` looks like {{.