# escaping templates in mustache

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I am basically new to rendering templates using mustache. I am trying to render a mustache file to a html. I have this situation where i have to escape certain template.

for eg.in the mustache file i have:

```
<div class="xyz">{{template}}</div>
```

in html i need to escape this & render the same like this:

```
<div class="xyz">{{template}}</div>
```

I tried few methods like using delimiters, no luck!
So whats the best way if you can guide me !?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mustache you cannot *escape* curly brackets however it recognize only literal braces, if you use an [HTML coded characters](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) instead of literal `{` (the same way you would escape `<` in HTML) then you can easily do it:

```
<div>
    This section contains &lt;this&gt; and &#123;&#123;this}}.
</div>
```

It'll result in:

```
<div>
    This section contains <this> and {{this}}.
</div>
```

Note that if there isn't opening `{{` then you don't need to escape closing `}}` with `&#125;&125;` (actually you need to escape just one opening curly, not both).

It works but if you have to insert a lot of `{{` then it may be annoying, fortunately you can change Mustache delimiter: see it in action in [documentation examples](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) about [Set Delimiter](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#set-delimiter) (it's `=` after current delimiter).

```
{{=<% %>=}}
```

Now delimiters aren't `{{` and `}}` but `<%` and `%>`. You're free to use `{{` and `}}` in your template, they won't be replaced (just remember to set default delimiters back).

```
{{=<% %>=}}
<div class="xyz">{{template}}</div>
<%={{ }}=%>
```

Output will be:

```
<div class="xyz">{{template}}</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your help. Works perfect! Also i should have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042926/how-does-one-use-a-literal-in-a-mustache-template

Comment: You welcome! I _usually_ prefer 2nd method when I'm working with strings from an external source (like DB) 'cause it's easy to perform search & replace in original string but first one is easier (maybe) when you directly write HTML.