# Elasticsearch phrase suggester collate returns false even if query brings results back

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have following phrase suggester template:

```
PUT /_search/template/DidYouMean
{
  "template": {
    "size": 0,
    "suggest": {
      "DidYouMean": {
        "text": "{{SearchPhrase}}",
        "phrase": {
          "field": "_all",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "size": 50,
          "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.9,
          "max_errors": 0.5,
          "gram_size": 3,
          "direct_generator": [
            {
              "field": "_all",
              "suggest_mode": "always",
              "min_word_length": 3
            }
          ],
          "collate": {
            "prune": true,
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "_all": {
                  "query": "{{suggestion}}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I run it using this query:

```
POST /my_index/_search/template
{
  "template": {
    "id": "DidYouMean"
  },
  "params": {
    "SearchPhrase": "unileve"
  }
}
```

And I'm expecting to get Unilever (a company) as a result with `"collate_match": true`, however, it's bringing back `false`. I'm getting this, even though I'm expecting Unilever to come with true:

```
{
   "took": 25,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 220692,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "suggest": {
      "DidYouMean": [
         {
            "text": "unileve",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 7,
            "options": [
               {
                  "text": "unilever",
                  "score": 0.016954133,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "unilevers",
                  "score": 0.005391976,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "unilet",
                  "score": 0.00062763924,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "uniline",
                  "score": 0.00062518474,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "unilerver",
                  "score": 0.00055350363,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "uniliver",
                  "score": 0.00055350363,
                  "collate_match": false
               },
               {
                  "text": "unielever",
                  "score": 0.0005243993,
                  "collate_match": false
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now when I run same query on its own, it brings result back.

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "unilever"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It does bring results back.

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4305,
      "max_score": 3.1709287,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "754743",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Iran Co"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "751585",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever UK Ltd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "10363",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever (Schweiz) AG"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "647311",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Taiwan Ltd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "651158",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Gulf FZE"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "654498",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever China Ltd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "654664",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever NV"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "650307",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Canada Ltd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "710125",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Ltd"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "companies",
            "_id": "722327",
            "_score": 3.1709287,
            "_source": {
               "CompanyName": "Unilever Croatia"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Am I misuderstanding purpose of collate? Or I am simply doing something completely wrong. Please advice.

Elasticsearch version: 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by myself.

Issues:

1. That I was creating a template.

   - `{{suggestion}}` was expected as a parameter, which was not supplied
   - So I understood that it's being rendered without it and match query was running against **nothing**

How did I fix it?

Query template needs to render `{{suggestion}}` somehow, so I've had to escape these characters. See this:

```
PUT /_search/template/DidYouMean
{
  "template": {
    "size": 0,
    "suggest": {
      "DidYouMean": {
        "text": "{{SearchPhrase}}",
        "phrase": {
          "field": "_all",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "size": 50,
          "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.9,
          "max_errors": 0.5,
          "gram_size": 3,
          "direct_generator": [
            {
              "field": "_all",
              "suggest_mode": "always",
              "min_word_length": 3
            }
          ],
          "collate": {
            "prune": true,
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "_all": {
                  "query": "{{=<% %>=}}{{suggestion}}<%={{ }}=%>"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[How does one use a literal {{ in a Mustache template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042926/how-does-one-use-a-literal-in-a-mustache-template) gives answer how this is done.

Now it renders this as a parameter, rather than expects something to be passed in